# Why were constructors for HttpWebRequest and HttpWebResponse removed from .NET?

Tags: c#, .net, httpwebrequest, httpwebresponse, system.net.httpwebrequest

Perhaps it doesn't make sense for product code to instantiate these types but the deprecation of the constuctors has made unit testing clients which use the `Http` implementations of `WebRequest/Response` far more trouble than it should be. I see no value in taking the constructors away and obvious value in having them, so what is the technical reason for their deprecation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hmm, why exactly do you need the constructor of `HttpWebRequest`? I can't see any preferences of it comparing with [`WebRequest.Create`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webrequest.create.aspx), which is being suggested as preffered way to create such requests in all the versions from the beginning.

This method is returning the `HttpWebRequest` as `WebRequest`, but you still can cast it to the direct type for your needs. If you'll provide some other protocols, as [`file://`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.filewebrequest.aspx) or [`ftp://`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.ftpwebrequest.aspx), it will return corresponding types.

I think that this [Obsolete list](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee461502.aspx) is a part of standardizing the .NET Core for all the platforms it'll be used, and it'll be much more simple to maintain the `WebRequest` creation in one single point of the code.

**Update**:
I think you've saw this article about [deriving the `WebRequest` class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3tf230ta.aspx), so I'll just write here another pack of my opinion:

When you are dering from the `WebRequest`, you need two points:

- implement [`IWebRequestCreate`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.iwebrequestcreate.aspx) interface
- register the class with the [`WebRequest.RegisterPrefix`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webrequest.registerprefix.aspx) method

As the MSDN says:

> The `HttpWebRequest` class is registered to service requests for HTTP and HTTPS schemes by default. Attempts to register a different `WebRequest` descendant for these schemes will fail.

So the Microsoft wants to control the `http` and `https` oriented classes and don't want anybody to replace this functionality with their own. I think that this could be done because of some security concerns. Sad but true.

Comment: `WebRequest.Create` is fine for instantiating request objects and could have been left out of the question. The problem is when you try to inherit from the class (particularly the `WebResponse`) or instantiate it for unit testing and you're not able to. For example if I have a deserialize method like `public T DeserializeResponse<T>(HttpWebResponse resp)` I have to use some impractical work around to test this instead of the obvious make instance pass to method, assert against `T`.

Comment: @evanmcdonnal Updated the answer, but still have no way to help you (I think that the question will sooner or later be closed as too broad)

Comment: Yeah that's alright. It somewhat doesn't fit the SO criteria cause it could be considered subjective. Thanks for the info. The steps you're talking about in deriving from WebRequest are exactly what I'm trying to do. I'm frustrated with my unit tests ability to do that for a `WebResponse` but not an `HttpWebResponse`. The thing is I'm trying to use a different scheme too (`test://`) then my test config will have that prefix instead of http for the urls.